# SKPayementQueue: restoring transactions finishes without calling 'updatedTransactions' in release config but not debug config

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm debugging restoring transactions and in my debug configuration everything works normally:

IE I call:

```
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

sometime later the queueCalls:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

and sometime after that it calls:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
```

and everyone is happy.

*BUT* in my release configuration, I never see the call to updatedTransactions and so I never actually restore the purchases.

possibly related, after I attempt the restore and it doesn't work.  I restart the application and I find that I don't get a response when I ask the store for a product list.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in storekit.

Comment: Posting the differences in your debug/release configuration would help. Is it only the code signing and optimizations that are different, or are there other changes as well?

Comment: StoreKit is really quite terrible; I think that Carl is right. I hope you get things worked out, but I wouldn't be surprised if this issue persists for a while.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Is this a bug 4 years later? Or was there some way to test differently or change the code?

Answer (score 1):

This error condition had nothing to do with the configuration.  It is an intermittent bug in store kit.

Answer (score 1):

Carl, as you said it seems to be an intermittent bug. 
However, I have also found out that it doesn't happen (or at least I haven't seen it yet) if I test it using the US Store. I've been using a UK test user and today it was failing miserably every single time. Created a US test user, and, after being switched to the US store automatically, it works perfectly again.
It is not a fix, but it may be useful ;)

Answer (score -1):

Do you add your payment object in the payment queue in this way?

SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:"Your Product identifier"];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

If you are using this way,then the UpdatedTransactions is called right after adding the payment object in the payment queue.You dont have to call it explicitly.It is handeled by store kit.

Comment: What does this have to do with the restoring problem from the OP?