# SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored not called for non-recurring subscription while restoring

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a problem in sandbox that no transactions with transactionState SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored being delivered to

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

after a called to

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

In fact it's not called at all.

Only the normal restore complete method

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

is called and queue.transactions.count is 0 as well (which make sens as no transactions was delivered).

I have created both us test users and non-us test users in itunes connect as well with no success.

My in app purchase is a non-recurring subscription for one month.

I have tried different devices as well as created a new in-app purchase in itunes connect as well but to no avail.

If I repurchase the in-app purchase I get a warning that I already bought a subscription which is expected and make good sense.

Base SDK is set to 5.1 and IOS deployment target is set to 5.0.

I am as far considering it as a sandbox problem...

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726654/skpayementqueue-restoring-transactions-finishes-without-calling-updatedtransac) I also faced this problem but not always so I think the oldest answer is correct.

Comment: Are you referring to that it might be a "intermittent bug" ?

Comment: yes seems like an intermittent bug & hopefully sandbox only

Comment: My problem is then that I have no way to test if my code is doing the right thing when restoring... Did you implement restoring and made it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While researching more I have found that Apple do NOT restore non-recurring subscription in-app purchases. You have to that yourself. This could be done by creating your own subscription server.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working with a subscription server? What details did you store? We cant use the deviceIdentifier anymore and cant get any details about the apple account.